# How to use the crossSectionEngine?

Tags: streaming, quantitative-finance, dolphindb

I set a cascaded crossSectionEngine and set the triggeringPattern to ‘perBatch’. Does the data in the following engine refresh after I insert one batch data into the first engine?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the parameter perBatch is to update the engine once a batch of data is injected.
For detailed parameter introduction, please refer to the introduction of createcrosssectionengine function

https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/c/createCrossSectionalEngine.html